# Link bigger than contained resized image in flexbox in grid. Firefox only

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to arrange two resized images right next to each other in a line in a grid cell, and want to use flexbox to do so.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ffe6e6, #90a7d5);
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

.header>a {
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header>a>img {
  min-width: 0;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg" />
      </a>
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In edge and chrome I receive the desired result:

[image: Edge Chrome]

Firefox on the other hand:

[image]

Inspecting tells me that the size of the  element is bigger than its containing image.
I assume that I need to set something extra for Firefox, but can't figure out what that would be.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is having a problem sizing the images in a nested flex container. If you switch to a nested grid container, the problem persists. This does not appear to be a problem in Chrome or Edge. If you remove the nested flex container, the images align as intended on all three browsers.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ffe6e6, #90a7d5);
  text-align: left;
  /* display: flex; <---- problem in Firefox */
  justify-content: start;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  /* text-align: left; **duplicate** */
}

.header>a {
  min-width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.header>a>img {
  min-width: 0;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg" />
      </a>
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg" />
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```